# how to fix this error ? 'flutter shared_preferences error'

Tags: flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences(31367): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences(31367): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1@c4b4f58 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@b56a9c2[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 5]
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences(31367):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem with version 2.0.3, but it was solved in version 2.0.4 released today